# Java eigensolvers

Tags: java, linear-algebra

Does anyone know of an eigensolver in Java that can give me just several smallest eigenvectors w/o computing the whole eigendecomposition (namely, second smallest EV)? I have looked at Colt, Jama, MTJ, UJMP, but these packages compute all eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this can help you, but this math library isn't on your list.

[Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/)

Comment: Specifically, might this meet your needs?

http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/linear.html#a3.5_Eigenvalueseigenvectors_and_singular_valuessingular_vectors

Comment: Nope, their implementation computes the whole decomposition and then gives you individual vectors. If matrix is huge, you don't want to do that if you only need two smallest eigenvectors

Answer (score 2):

Can you describe your matrix in more detail?  Is it sparse?  In general, sparse linear algebra packages have methods to compute only a few of the smallest or largest eigenpairs.  For example, you can try to use ARPACK from within Java.

Another idea is just to write your own version of the Power Method, which is good at finding
a few extreme eigenvalues very quickly.  For example, see
[Eigenvalue Template Book (Hermitian)](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~dongarra/etemplates/node94.html) if your matrix is Hermitian or [Eigenvalue Template Book (non-Hermitian)](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~dongarra/etemplates/node210.html)
if your matrix is non-Hermitian.

Comment: My colleague and I looked at using [netlib-java](http://code.google.com/p/netlib-java/) as a wrapper for ARPACK, but the code didn't compile.
Matrix is sparse, symmetric, real, size can vary from 1000 to 10000.

Comment: My colleagues have had good luck using netlib, so I would recommend trying to get it to work.  That matrix is rather small, so you should be able to easily implement your own method as I described above.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

MTJ includes the netlib-java and has a wrapper to use arpack,
so one can solve for a set number of eigenvalues and there are
choices on the attributes of those.

See
https://github.com/fommil/matrix-toolkits-java/blob/master/src/test/java/no/uib/cipr/matrix/sparse/ArpackSymTest.java

and
http://static.javadoc.io/com.googlecode.matrix-toolkits-java/mtj/1.0.4/no/uib/cipr/matrix/sparse/ArpackSym.html